# Purchase order saved search created from salesorder and salesorder field

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

1. I have some purchase order records in netsuite which starts with "Salesorder".i.e, They are created from salesorders.
2. A Custom field in Salesorder called as- Salesorder field (custom body) which is in text form.
3. I need to create a purchase order saved search which starts with "Salesorder" & also created from : that salesorder , along with this - Within the salesorder record, as mentioned there is custom field it should not be empty.

I tried creating a saved search of purchase order but am unable to retreive the records which starts with SalesOrder & custom field which is not empty.

Comment: you want to get only purchase orders which are created from the particular sales order? Please describe more your question. tell exact requirement.

Comment: Saved search - Type is Purchase order, 
Created from salesorder record and also a custom field in that particular salesorder record should not be empty